# I don't need shiro.ini on spring webmvc

Tags: spring-mvc, shiro

I'm developing a web application based on spring webmvc and apache shiro.

I made JpaRealm class which extends AuthorizingRealm, and it is instantiated by Spring context in order to inject dependency (UserService).

I don't need shiro.ini file because all of configurations are overriden by spring-context.xml.

If I delete it, the default listener compains because the default IniWebEnvironment always tries to load shiro.ini.

I'd like to ask the custom listener which load the custom environment extends DefaultWebEnvironment.

I copied someone's code from the Internet, but I failed.

```
public class JpaRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaRealm.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public JpaRealm() {
    HashedCredentialsMatcher credentialsMatcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
    credentialsMatcher.setHashAlgorithmName(Sha256Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
    setCredentialsMatcher(credentialsMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

    SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = null;

    UsernamePasswordToken userPassToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;

    String username = userPassToken.getUsername();

    if (username != null && !username.equals("")) {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        logger.debug("doGetAuthenticationInfo invoked");
        logger.debug("username: " + username);

        info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, user.getPassword(), getName());
    }

    return info;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {

    AuthorizationInfo authorizationInfo = null;

    if (principals != null) {
        logger.debug("doGetAuthorizationInfo invoked");

        String username = (String) getAvailablePrincipal(principals);

        return userService.getAuthorizationInfoByUser(username);
    }

    return authorizationInfo;
    }

}
```

security-context.xml

```
<bean id="jpaRealm" class="foo.bar.JpaRealm" />

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="jpaRealm" />
</bean>

<bean id="verboseFormAuthenticationFilter"
    class="foo.bar.VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="/" />
    <property name="usernameParam" value="username" />
    <property name="passwordParam" value="password" />
    <property name="rememberMeParam" value="rememberMe" />
    <property name="failureKeyAttribute" value="yamShiroLoginFailure" />
</bean>

<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />

    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized.jsp" />

    <property name="filters">
        <map>
            <entry key="authc" value-ref="verboseFormAuthenticationFilter" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /**=authc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from the manual, and it works fine.

shiroEnvironmentClass can be replaced as a context-param as follows:

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- IniWebEnvironment is not requied because shiro.ini is not necessary. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>shiroEnvironmentClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.shiro.web.env.DefaultWebEnvironment</param-value>
</context-param>
```